# Getting an error while invoking a chaincode

Tags: node.js, bash, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to invoke chaincode,multiple times simultaneously using curl commands which are fired from the script file. Chaincode is not getting invoked for all the times , its getting invoked only for some. I am getting following error
[image: isEnrolled error]
Due to this i am getting one more error
[image: getSigningIdentity]

Can somebody help me in this regard? Why only for few chaincode is getting invoked but not for all?
Thanks in advance